# How to redirect after login in Spring Security for specific cases only?

Tags: kotlin, spring-security

I want my login page to redirect to another one, if `forward` parameter is specified in the URL. Otherwise, I want it to redirect wherever the user wanted to go.

So say I have a route `/print` that is secured. When the user click some button, I manually forward him to this URL

```
http://localhost:8080/login?forward=print?p=5d1666a775d2f02064dcdf06
```

because if he chooses `Sign Up` from the login screen, I can remember where he was going initially.

So I have set up an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`

```
@Bean
open fun authenticationSuccessHandler(): AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    val redirectStrategy = DefaultRedirectStrategy()
    return AuthenticationSuccessHandler { request, response, _ -> redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, request.getParameter("forward")) }
}
```

But now, if the user just types this URL without signing in

```
http://localhost:8080/print?p=5d1666a775d2f02064dcdf06
```

Spring Security redirects him to login page, and after login, my `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` forwards him to home page as the `forward` parameter is missing. I can check whether the param exists or not, but don't know where to redirect if the param's missing. In other words

```
@Bean
open fun authenticationSuccessHandler(): AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    val redirectStrategy = DefaultRedirectStrategy()
    return AuthenticationSuccessHandler{ request, response, _ -> 
        if(!request.getParameter("forward").isNullOrEmpty()) {
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, request.getParameter("forward"))
        }else {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

what should I write instead of my `TODO`?

Or maybe there is some elegant way to save the initial state of where the user wanted to go when I redirect him from login page to signup page?

Comment: I read it about 5 times, and i still can't understand your problem.
If the `forward` param exists, then you redirect to the `forward` value, otherwise you can redirect wherever you want, main page or home page...

Comment: Say user wants to go to /print and /print is restricted. He is being forwarded to /login. If he sings in, he get's redirected to /print. But what if he presses `Sign up` on the login page? He gets redirected to signup page, and when he does sign up, he doesn't get redirected to /print, because I don't know exactly where he wanted to go initially.

Comment: Now i understood you better.

Comment: In this case, you can either save it in cache and after sign up redirect to the value from the cache or redirect the user to the main page always because if a new user signing in my expectation is to get to the home/main pages, and not to a specific page (most of the new users doesn't know how to use the app, or where to navigate inside it). But it is your choice.